# Convert inputstream to file all extensions

Tags: java, file

I am converting an `InputStream` to file using below code snippet. This is creating file in temp location. But when I get PDF/Word/XLS as an inputstream. This is corrupting the file and I am unable to use this file object for other operations. I know I have to set content-type/Mime type. I tried giving the prefix and suffix matching my requirement but it didn't work.

```
public static final String PREFIX = "stream2file";
public static final String SUFFIX = ".tmp";

public static File stream2file (InputStream in) throws IOException {
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile(PREFIX, SUFFIX);
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

I don't know what has to be added in this code snippet while creating the temporary file so that I can retrieve all the files without corrupting.

Comment: I don't have any objection on your program. Have you tried not to delete the new file, and open it with an external editor to confirm it is openable?

Comment: PDF file opens up but it doesnot have any contents on it. Just a blank document

Comment: Have you checked the number of bytes copied, returned by `IOUtils.copy`?